# Reading Double and String from .txt file not showing all records

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I am trying to read the following data from a text file:

```
3.8 Lisa
3.6 John
3.9 Susan
3.7 Kathy
3.4 Jason
3.9 David
3.4 Jack
3.9 Andy
3.8 Fox
3.9 Minnie
2.7 Goofy
3.9 Doc
3.4 Danny
```

I am then sorting and printing it. However my output is removing duplicate items and I need the full list to display.

Output:

```
run:
2.7 Goofy
3.4 Danny
3.6 John
3.7 Kathy
3.8 Fox
3.9 Doc
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Here is my code:

```
package highestgpa;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("StudentGPA.txt"));
        Map<Double, String> items = new TreeMap<Double, String>();

        String line;
        while (null != (line = br.readLine()))
        {
            String[] line_parts = line.split(" ");
            if (line_parts.length > 1)
            {
                StringBuilder desc = new StringBuilder(line_parts[1]);
                for (int i = 2; i < line_parts.length; i++)
                {
                    desc.append(line_parts[i]);
                }
                items.put(new Double (line_parts[0]), desc.toString());
            }
        }

        for (Double key: items.keySet())
        {
            System.out.println(key + " " + items.get(key));
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: "However my output is removing duplicate items" - well yes, you're using a `TreeMap`. How do you expect to get multiple values for a single entry in a map? It sounds like you want a MultiMap...

Answer (score 1):

You're using the GPA as a key. When you read in someone with the same GPA and add it to the map, it replaces the previous entry with that same GPA key.

Instead, try using the name as the key.

```
Map<String, Double> items = new TreeMap<String, Double>();

...

items.put( desc.toString(),new Double (line_parts[0]));

...

for (String key: items.keySet())
{
  System.out.println(key + " " + items.get(key));
}
```

Comment: I believe the expected output is an ordered list by GPA. This solution also removes duplicate names.

Comment: @cricket_007 is correct. I was looking to order the list by GPA as well. Suggestions?